# offset value varied in desktop firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, svg

Please check my code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGQas/130/) link,

Code :

```
<body>
  <div id="content" style="width:400px; height:110px;">
     <svg id="circle" height="300" width="300">
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
      </svg>
    </div>
 <div>     
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

 function myFunction() {
        var a = $(document.getElementById("circle")).offset().top;
        alert(a);
    }
```

When i run this i got 0 value in all browser both laptop and desktop but the top value can be varied only in firefox(in desktop not lap)... please give a better solution..

how to solve this?

Comment: change jQuery version to 1.10.1 in the fiddle and check http://jsfiddle.net/sGQas/131/

Comment: @yasin checked but this issue was reproduce only in firefox below version 30

Answer (score 0):

use below code .  check demo on [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/fm3v2qwh/)

```
function myFunction() {
    var a = $("#circle").offset().top;
    alert(a);
}
```

Comment: hi this is ok please check this same code in destop firefox the value can be varies that's was my issue

Comment: @AkbarBasha i check in all browser in my desktop . safari,firefox.chrome. same value return .

Comment: @AkbarBasha   FF version is 36.0.1 on MAC os ..sorry i don't have laptop here :)

Comment: @AkbarBasha  i have checked your fiddle also . it gives 0 on my FF :)

Comment: Firefox 30 was end-of-lifed some time ago.

Comment: :) . now i am not able to check issue . don't have older version